# Is it possible to make UEFI settings ON/OFF using PowerShell command in a virtual machine?

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, uefi

I want to create a Virtual Machine in Azure with security Type as Trusted Launch where security profile has UEFI settings like SecureBoot and vTPM enabled.

Now, Once VM is deployed I want to turn off the UEFI settings, and Vice Versa using PowerShell command. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of below **`Az`** PowerShell commands to turn **UEFI settings** `ON` in Azure virtual machine.

```
$VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -VMName "vm_name"  
Set-AzVMUefi -VM $VM -EnableVtpm $true -EnableSecureBoot $true
Update-AzVM -VM $VM -ResourceGroupName "rg_name"
```

While creating virtual machine, these settings will be **enabled** by default like below:

[image]

To turn above **UEFI settings** `OFF` in Azure virtual machine, you can make use of below **`Az`** PowerShell command by including **$false** in it like this:

```
$VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -VMName "vm_name"  
Set-AzVMUefi -VM $VM -EnableVtpm $false -EnableSecureBoot $false
Update-AzVM -VM $VM -ResourceGroupName "rg_name"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, settings are disabled successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Set-AzVMUefi (Az.Compute) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmuefi?view=azps-10.1.0)